# Is there a way to disable the generation and deployment of Maven sites in Maven 2.2.1?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-site-plugin

We are in the process of upgrading our build processes and infrastructure. The majority of the projects are still stuck using Maven `2.2.1` (we have hundreds of Maven projects across a number of environment on different Hudson and Jenkins servers). An immediate upgrade to 3.3.x will most-certainly break things for us due to the number of teams affected and large amount of projects which haven't been looked after, or have become obsolete.

As part of the migration, we would temporarily like to disable the generation and deployment of Maven sites. In the more recent versions of the maven-site-plugin there is there are two properties that would have come quite handy - `maven.site.skip` and `maven.site.deploy.skip`, however we are unfortunately stuck Maven `2.2.1` where these versions are completely ignored.

Is there another way to disable this?

Comment: If a site is generated somewhere must be something like this : `mvn site...`?

Comment: @khmarbaise: That is true, but we also have this being invoked via extending parents and also specifically defined in projects themselves. We'd like to switch it off in our Hudson/Jenkins sites for the time-being.

Comment: If the appropriate maven-site plugin versions don't support that you have to change the parent pom's or explicitly forbid in the projects them selfs...

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "explicitly forbid in the projects themselves"...? The plugin version we're using is < `3.0` which is where these properties were introduced.

Comment: If you don't add a site section inside distributionManagement http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Site_Distribution the site will not be uploaded. So remove that section from the pom might help in your situation. Plan B: use file:///dev/null for the site deployment?

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of unmaintained projects which may, or may not be dead. Its out of our control to change most of them, so bumping the version of the parents may be tricky, as we're talking about several hundred projects over a dozen Hudson and Jenkins servers. The `file:///dev/null` sounds like an epic hack worth the try! Thanks for the suggestion (you should probably put it down as an answer)! I'm open to any other suggestions as well!

Comment: @wemu: Have you actually tried the `file:///dev/null` solution? It seems to fail, as it tried to create directories under `/dev/null`. It sounds like a neat hack, but I'm either doing something wrong, or this doesn't seem to possible.

Comment: @wemu: Based on your idea, we might as well deploy to `/tmp/maven-sites` for the time-being. Thanks! You should put it as an answer, so I could accept it! ;)

Comment: naa - I haven't tried that /dev/null workaround - glad you have found a way to live with the circumstances :)

Comment: Yeah... workarounds in such old environments are life-saviors, if you want to push things forward and modernize things step by step... Sometimes you just can't do it in one go.

Comment: @wemu, post it as an answer, so I can accept it! This worked for us! Thanks!

Comment: ok. I will do that in a second. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably is no "clean" way to do this but some possibilities exist:

If you don't add a `site` section inside `<distributionManagement/>` the site will not be uploaded. See: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Site_Distribution
So remove that section from the pom might help in your situation.

Another try would be to deploy the site to `/tmp/maven-sites` by specifying `file:///tmp/maven-sites` for the site deployment url. Unfortunately, deploying to `file:///dev/null` would not work, as the `maven-site-plugin` would need to be able to create files and directories. :)

Comment: Just slightly polished your answer. Thanks for this! I'm sure some other chap will run into this sort of thing at one point or another...